# Trying to set up port forwarding for SSH on my router

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

Recently I got a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I setup SSH on my device successfully and was able to access it throughout my local network. I have decided that it would be convenient to have the ability to access it outside my local network. Therefore I proceeded to open up my router settings and go to the Port Forwarding section. I have tried multiple times to successfully setup Port Forwarding but have had no success.

Router: Sagemcom F@st 5260 (running Spectrum firmware)

Picture: [Port Forwarding Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7uKy.png)

Comment: Your external host has to be your static, public IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **@Appleoddity** mentioned, your external host IP address has to be your public IP address. 
Check what is your public IP address [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/).

Then, you will be able to connect to your Raspberry Pi via:

```
ssh <username>@<public_ip>
```

You can also change your **External port** setting. That way, you can setup port forwarding to SSH services on multiple machines, or just migrate it from the default **22** port which is insecure. You can access via SSH in the following way after changing the external port:

```
ssh -p <external_port> <username>@<public_ip>
```

Comment: I tried to put in my IPv6 address and it says that it isn't a valid IP address. It only lets me put in an IPv4 address.

Comment: There is no such thing as IPv6 port forwarding afaik. Or are you talking about SSH? Have you tried `ssh -6` or have you tried checking your `sshd_config`? In it, there is a setting `AddressFamily` or something like that. It must be `any`, not just `inet`.